# Which design pattern a composed object just for proxy purposes relates?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have my object D which encapsulates different structs(A,B,C in this example). D is mostly for being passed as an parameter to an object called "RealClientInterface". Because D composed of A,B,C which "RealClientInterface" needs to run its functions.

My question if D relates to a design pattern? If it does which design pattern(s) D relates in this case?

Is it a composer since it is being composed of A,B,C?
Or it is proxy or builder? Since it is there just as an proxy the real read/write is being done by RealClientInterface?

I need this information for giving a good name to my class D and also documentation purposes.

```
struct A
{
    //Some data
};

struct B 
{
    //Some data
};

struct C 
{
    //Some data
};

struct D 
{
   A a;
   B b; 
   C c;
};

struct RealClientInterface
{
    void foo ( D& d )
    {
        //reads d.a and inserts d.b
    }

    void foo2 ( D& d )
    {
        //reads d.c and inserts d.b and d.c
    }

    // Many other functions
} ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class containing other classes for whatever reason is not a familiar design pattern, it is just a composition, which is a concept meaning a class containing other classes. The class could also contains references to other classes (aggregation) or it could inherit.  You can find more information on composition [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/102-composition/).

You can find an [overview of common design patterns on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), but I don't think this is in there.

Answer (score 0):

No, D doesn't relate to any of design patterns. In your case D is just a container for objects a, b and c of type A, B and C respectively. 'Container' would be a suitable name to use in your documentation.

Comment: Except that the standard library uses container for array and dictionary like classes.

Comment: @stefaanv, do you think it will be confusing?

Answer (score 0):

No, in current form this doesn't look like any design pattern, but

- If D would control access to A, B, C => Proxy Pattern
- If D would simplify interface of A, B, C => Facade Pattern